# Setting UIViewController preferredContentSize not working in iOS 17

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios17

In iOS 17, I am having an issue where UIPopoverPresentationControllers are not retaining the preferred size of the UIViewController they contain.

The following method uses a UIPopoverPresentationController `popoverVC` to display a UIViewController `contentVC` from a UIView `view` anchor location `frame`.

```
+ (void) showDialogiPad:(UIViewController *)contentVC
       fromPresentingVC:(UIViewController *)presentingVC
                 inView:(UIView *)view
                atFrame:(CGRect)frame
          withDirection:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)direction {
    
    // Set content view controller size
    contentVC.preferredContentSize = contentVC.view.frame.size; // size should be 320x480
        
    // Choose the presentation style in which the content is
    // displayed in a popover view
    contentVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    
    // Set the popover size and anchor location
    contentVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = frame;
    contentVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = view;
    
    // Present the popover presentation controller
    [presentingVC presentViewController:contentVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The `contentVC`'s size gets set in it's `viewDidLoad` method as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the size of this view controller (which is used in a popup view controller)
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    
    // Set a border around the view
    CALayer *layer = self.view.layer;
    layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    layer.borderWidth = 2;
    layer.cornerRadius = 10;
}
```

Prior to iOS 17, the code displayed the popover as expected as shown here:

[image]

Now however, since the update to iOS 17, the popover is now squashed and displayed as:

[image]

A few observations:

- The popover dialog actually displays properly the first time you open it. Every subsequent time you open it, it is squashed.
- When I comment out the line that sets the `preferredContentSize`, the popover opens at the max size every time - so it shows all the content but it is not set to the size I want it to be.
- If I leave `preferredContentSize` as is but change `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, the size of the popover is correct but the popover always presents in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that in many cases, instead of externally setting a view controller's `preferredContentSize` property to some value, it works better if the given view controller overrides the `preferredContentSize` property. This also has the benefit of putting the knowledge of the preferred size in the view controller itself.

```
- (CGSize)preferredContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(width: 320, height: 480);
}
```